# Looking to make MySQL db records readable as CSV-like lines in text file via standard file io interface Linux device driver (working with legacy code)

Tags: mysql, file-io, device-driver, plaintext, emulation

I want to be able to read from a real live proper MySQL database using standard file access routines. I don't mean reading the MySQL database's own underlying private files. What I mean is implementing a file-based linux device driver that "presents" a MySQL database as a file. In other words,  the text file is a "View" of the MySQL database. The MySQL records are presented in our homegrown custom variation of the CSV format that the legacy code was originally written to understand.

**Background**

I have some legacy code that reads from a text file that contains a very large table of data, each line being a separate record. New records (lines) need to be added but there is contention for the file among the team, there is also an overhead in deployment of the legacy code and this file to many systems when releasing the software to them. The text file itself also needs to be version controlled.

Rather than modify the legacy code to call a MYSQL database version of these records directly, I thought it would be better to leave it untouched. This would avoid risks in modifying the code and ease deployment and moreover, modifying the code would cause much overhead in de-risking, design discussions, more testing etc.

So what I'm looking to do is write a file-based device driver such that this makes the MySQL database appear as a file to the legacy code, with the data within the format that the legacy code expects. That way the legacy code is not changed and can work oblivious that the file is really an underlying database. Contention is removed because the individual records in the database can now be updated/added to separately (via MySQL, or even better a separate web admin interface that guides and validates data entry from the user for individual records) and deployment effort is much reduced without having to up-issue the whole file on all the systems that use it.

The device driver would contain routines to internally translate standard file read operations into MySQL queries to the MySQL database and contain routines to return the MySQL results and translate these into the text format for returning back to the file read operation.

This is for a Linux/Unix platform.

Has this been done and what are your thoughts?

(cleaned up the question, grammar, clarification, readability. This does not affect the accepted answer.)

Comment: You could implement a virtual network drive instead of a local file system. I'm not sure if it's any easier but at least you may not need an admin access

Comment: Actually, Windows can link FTP directories as network drives. You could convince the app to talk over FTP this way. Implementing a FTP server should be easier than making a driver.

Comment: Sorry folks, I should add that this is a Linux/Unix environment. The FTP idea may be consideration, but it does mean changing the code which my requirement states I could not (ownership issues).

Comment: Why changing the code? As long as the app can access a network drive (which is your FTP server), no code change is neccessary. You could even create a symlink from the datafile's expected location to your network drive.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Linux can mount FTP drives into the file system.

Comment: @JanDvorak This is an abstraction in user-space provided by desktop frameworks (e.g.  Gnome and KDE) and relies on the application using the framework's abstracted IO library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of thing has been done before - an obvious example being the dynamic view filing system in [ClearCase](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/clearcase/) which provided (maybe still does?) a virtualised view onto a version control repository. Behind the scenes it implemented an object cache and used RPC to fetch objects from other hosts if necessary, and made extensive use of both local and remote databases.

It's fairly clear that you are going to implement the bulk of your filing system in user-space, but you will need a (small) kernel resident portion. Unless there's a really good reason to do otherwise, [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net) is what you're looking for  - it will provide the kernel-resident part for you.   All you'll need to write is glue to turn file operations into SQL requests.

Comment: +1 vote, great answer and accepted, perfect, thanks! Yes, now I think of it, I see what you mean by a ClearCase example. Thanks for the link to FUSE, intriguing, it's great to see something that already provides some of the nuts and buts that I'm looking for. I'm excited! My obstacles now are getting enough time to study this and invest the effort, and also overcoming mindsets in my organisation to move to this approach, away from the rather inefficient current deployment system as I had described.

Comment: Further thoughts (thinking out loud, I can research myself) I would have to deal with concurrency - because many machines will want to read from this file. Fortunately the problem is not too complex in that regard as they are only doing reads (it would be quite a different (i.e. complex problem) if it was write as well! TOCTOU - Time of Check to Time of use issues.)

Comment: Encouragingly, thanks to your initial lead on FUSE, @Marko, I've been able to discover from searching that quite a few github projects have done something similar with FUSE and MySQL: 1. https://github.com/fuse4x/fuse 2. https://github.com/pld-linux/fuse-mysqlfs 3. https://github.com/MigNov/Fuse-db 4. https://github.com/jackdoe/sfs https://github.com/bianster/mysqlfs 5. https://github.com/skeyby/mysqlfs 6. https://github.com/arialdomartini/mysqlfs 7. https://github.com/kstep/fusqlfs